# Alter values in two differrent lines with awk

Tags: awk

I have a parameter card that's fixed. I need to change the value of lines 10 and 20, I am trying using awk but so far didn't get it. Those positions are fixed, so I will need to do this with a loop but it will be always the same 2 lines, lines 10 and 20. I tried this way but it changes the $1 of all lines from 10 to 20. Since I will be changing these values I cannot use sed to match a pattern because I won't have one, the values will be random each time, only the lines are fixed.

```
awk 'FNR==10,FNR==20{$1="new_value"}1' dummycard.txt > dummynew.txt
```

Thatś my file:

```
DATAFILE
p365.txt
TRAITS
2
FIELDS_PASSED TO OUTPUT

WEIGHT(S)

RESIDUAL_VARIANCE
300
EFFECT
3 cross numer
EFFECT
1 cross numer
RANDOM
animal
FILE
pednem.txt
(CO)VARIANCES
200
OPTION conv_crit 1d-12
Convergence criterion (default 1d-10).
OPTION maxrounds 10000
maximum rounds (default 5000).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give OR condition for FNR checking.

```
awk 'FNR==10 || FNR==20{$1="new_value"}1' Input_file
```

OR as per Ed sir's suggestion, you could try:

```
awk 'FNR ~ /^[12]0$/{$1="new_value"}1' Input_file
```

---

---

In case you want to have your new value in an awk variable then try following.

```
awk -v new_value="10" 'FNR==10 || FNR==20{$1=new_value}1' Input_file
```

For example I have set its value to 10 you could set it as per your need.

***Why OP's code didn't work:*** Since OP is using `,` between line numbers so it is taken as a range thus all lines changed from line numbers 10 to 20.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I need to build a script that will basically get values from a text file, do some math and save it in another file, in your opinion, is better to stick with awk for that or could I use something like python instead?

Comment: @PauloBarros, your welcome, using awk or python it fully depends on your use cases if your maths is complex(and your project is big) go for python or for small projects awk is great. Cheers and happy learning.

Comment: You could alternatively use `FNR ~ /^(10|20)$/` so you don't have to keep typing `FNR ==` if you have several values to compare it to. You could abbreviate that to `FNR ~ /^[12]0$/` in this particular case but it doesn't matter...

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you sir, I am in cab will add it once I am on desk :) cheers

Comment: There is a way to do this substitution without using a "temp" file, kind of just overwriting the original file, or I can't because I am using it as an input? when I do `awk -v nvG=230 'FNR==20{$1=nvG;print}1' card_p365.txt > temp
awk 'FNR==20{$1=$1;print}1' temp > card_p365.txt` the resulting file now has 3 identical lines from the substitution, like `new_value new_value new_value`

Comment: `DATAFILE
p365.txt
TRAITS
2
FIELDS_PASSED TO OUTPUT

WEIGHT(S)

RESIDUAL_VARIANCE
300
EFFECT
3 cross numer
EFFECT
1 cross numer
RANDOM
animal
FILE
pednem.txt
(CO)VARIANCES
230
230
230
OPTION conv_crit 1d-12
Convergence criterion (default 1d-10).
OPTION maxrounds 10000
maximum rounds (default 5000).`

Comment: @PauloBarros, I am sorry, I didn't get it. Request you to please open a new thread, one question one thread only else future users will be confused, cheers.